# using sqldatareader with where clause in query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need to read a specific value from the table, to use it in my field.
But when I insert the where clause in query, it gets me null value, nothing more.

My code is:

```
string query_select_id = "SELECT * from table1 WHERE column1=@value";

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString);
try
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand createCommand = new SqlCommand(query_select_id, con);
    createCommand .Parameters.Add("@value", SqlDbType.Int).Value  =Convert.ToInt32(textbox.Text);

    SqlDataReader dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        intvalue= dr.GetInt32(12); 
        // 12 is the index of a column in table of the value I wanna get
    }
    con.Close();

    textboxvalue.Text = intvalue.ToString();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: can you post the data you get after running the query in sql server management studio. It lets us know about the data structure.

Comment: have you executed this `SELECT * from table1 WHERE column1=XXX` in SqlServer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only one value, you should use [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) method. I use TOP 1 and column name to ensure that only one value is returned from select statement.

```
string query_select_id = "SELECT TOP 1 COLUMN12 from table1 WHERE column1=@value";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString);
int intvalue;
try
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand createCommand = new SqlCommand(query_select_id, con);
    createCommand.Parameters.Add("@value", SqlDbType.Int).Value  =Convert.ToInt32(textbox.Text);
    object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if(result == null)
    {
        textboxvalue.Text = "Result is NULL";
    }
    else
    {

        intvalue = (int) result; 
        textboxvalue.Text = intvalue.ToString();
    }
    con.Close();


}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very bad idea to use `SELECT *` instead of `SELECT column1` and `dr.GetInt32(12)` (constant index of value in the result). Try `SELECT column1 FROM table1 WHERE column1=@value` and use `ExecuteScalar()` to get the only result instead of `SqlDataReader` and `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Change `createCommand.Parameters.Add` into `createCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue`**

```
    string query_select_id = "SELECT * from table1 WHERE column1=@value";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString);

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand createCommand = new SqlCommand(query_select_id, con);
        //createCommand .Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", SqlDbType.Int).Value=Convert.ToInt32(textbox.Text);
        createCommand .Parameter.AddWitheValue("@value",textbox.Text);
        SqlDataReader dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            intvalue= dr.GetInt32(12); 
        // 12 is the index of a column in table of the value I wanna get

        }
        con.Close();

        textboxvalue.Text = intvalue.ToString();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```